# Why do I not get the expected result when concatenating a square wave and f(x)=x^2?

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

When I plot each `t` and `f` variable individually, I get the 4 parts of the signal I am looking for, but when I concatenate them it is not resulting in the signal I am expecting.

Here is the wave I am trying to replicate:

[image]

Here is the current output I am getting:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
T = 0.5
dutycycle = 0.5
samples = 10000

t2 = np.linspace(-0.5, 0, samples)
f2 = square(2*np.pi/T*t2, duty=dutycycle)
t3 = np.linspace(0.5, 1, samples)
f3 = square(2*np.pi/T*t3, duty=dutycycle)
t4 = np.linspace(-1, -0.5, samples)
f4 = (t4)**2
t5 = np.linspace(0, 0.5, samples)
f5 = (t5)**2
t = np.concatenate((t2, t3, t4, t5))
f = np.concatenate((f2, f3, f4, f5))

plt.plot(t, f, label="$x(t)$")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Welcome to SO! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please put the code as a text in the question so we can easily read it, copy-past it and comment it. And put image directly in the question and not as a text.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Sorry about that! I added my code, but looks like I need 10 reputation points to add the picture directly.

Comment: Your `t#` should be concatenated in numeric order.  Did you look at `t` and `f` before trying to plot them (or after)?  Do the values look reasonable?  `t` should be increasing from -1 to 1.

Comment: @hpaulj I rearranged the functions in numerical order and the results are looking more reasonable. My square wave y values need to from 0 to 1 rather than -1 to 1, so I will figure that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The order of points in [plt.plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) matters in a line-plot. You put the time-intervals not in ascending order. In your example, you need to change the lines:

```
t = np.concatenate((t2, t3, t4, t5))
f = np.concatenate((f2, f3, f4, f5))
```

to

```
t = np.concatenate((t4, t2, t5, t3))
f = np.concatenate((f4, f2, f5, f3))
```

because, the `t4` vector you created starts at `-1`, etc.